# How do I read 1 byte from STDIN?

Tags: haskell

How do I read one byte from STDIN?

I tried [searching for `IO Word8` on Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=IO%20Word8) but there is nothing useful.

The closest I can find is [`System.IO.getChar`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/System-IO.html), but it reads a `Char` not a `Word8`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest option is to use [`hGet`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.11.3.0/docs/Data-ByteString.html#v:hGet) from Data.ByteString like this:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import System.IO (stdin)
import Data.Word (Word8)

getByte :: IO Word8
getByte = B.head <$> B.hGet stdin 1
```

You can alternatively use [`hSetBinaryMode`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hSetBinaryMode) like this:

```
import System.IO
import Data.Word (Word8)

getByte :: IO Word8
getByte = do
  hSetBinaryMode stdin True
  c <- getChar
  hSetBinaryMode stdin False
  pure $! fromIntegral (fromEnum c)
```

Comment: `getByte = B.head <$> B.hGet stdin 1` also works